# Android Studio isn't working AGAIN

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass, google-gdk, android-studio-2.1

Before AS was refusing to install the APK onto the Glass so I uninstalled it, deleted all the files, and reinstalled AS using the installer file downloaded from the website. I downloaded and updated all the APIs I need and now it is coming up with one of two errors:

> IDE internal error occurred
>
> Failed to set up Android modules in project 'My Application'

or

> Error:Module 'app': platform 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19' not found.

This is happening on both my desktop and my laptop(which I didn't reinstall AS on). There doesn't seem to be any pattern to these errors and I don't know what to do, each error I fix just uncovers another error.

Comment: Try re-importing the project. Go to **file** -> **new** -> **import project**. Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe AS is not looking in the right place for the SDK.

Change the location of the SDK and try again. If it still doesn't work, try to delete all the SDK files (or move them elsewhere). **Warning!!!** This will take a long time to re-download the files.

If it still doesn't work then you will have to take a backup of your project (copy the whole project folder), then delete the project from AS. Then make a new project and copy the program and everything back.

That's all I can help with.